# Are there any prefered style when declaring default parameters in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep

Are there any preferred ways of how a default parameter should look when declaring it in a function? See the examples below:

Here is how I currently do it:

```
def my_func(count = 99):
    return count
```

Here is how pretty much everyone else does it (I'm referring to the spaces before and after the "=" sign):

```
def my_func(count=99):
    return count
```

The reason why I have a space before and after the equals sign is due to readability; for me, it seems a bit easier to read.

Comment: Don't worry about style, just use [black](https://pypi.org/project/black/). But this could be a very personal opinion, but it's PEP8 complaint : )

Comment: Don't use spaces before or after `=` for default values and there is no space before `:` but there is one after; see relevant [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEP 8 [says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations):

> Don't use spaces around the = sign when used to indicate a keyword argument, or when used to indicate a default value for an unannotated function parameter

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much whatever lol
Just as long as you make legible, simple code
without 10 for's inside a list comprehension...
ss long as is legible, everything is fine.

I like to do this when I code for example

```
variable = value
idk      = value
isajd    = value

dictionary = { asdsad: asdasd,
               sdsd  : sdfaf,
               as    : fasf,}
```

If you're still worried and would to know how to write properly, I recommend downloading PyCharm which will warn you every time you don't write the code properly (PEP8)

Comment: It may be opinion based, but we can surely all agree that this isn't right. See e.g. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#pet-peeves

Comment: IMO this kind of "pretty formatting" is a phase in developers life many of us went through before realizing it really isn't right.

Comment: Well, was kinda a salty answer, since there are some things in PEP8 that are negligible imho.  like 'identation is not a multiple of four' or 'expected 2  blank lines after function'.

Comment: There are others that i agree though. But when coding in jupyter or vs code  I'm more worried debugging than seeing pep8 style